# Java generics: compilation failure using captures

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, capture

Why does the below code fail to compile? Can this example be simplified (to fewer classes) to demonstrate equivalent error?

The error message produced is:

**func(capture of ? extends A) in ... cannot be aplied to B**

```
    private static interface A {}
    private static class B implements A {}

    private static class C<T> {
        private final T t;
        private C(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
        private void func(T t) {}
    }

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        B b = new B();
        C<? extends A> c = new C<B>(b);
        c.func(b); // fails here
    }
```

Comment: The `d` is unnecessary, you can't compile `c.func(b)` either.

Comment: Updated with // fails here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `C<? extends A>` means "It's a `C<T>` for some type `T`, but I don't know which type it is - only that it's something which extends `A`."

That means you *can't* assume that `T = B`, or that there's a conversion from `B` to `T`. But that's exactly what you *do* try to assume here:

```
c.func(b);
```

To demonstrate why it's invalid, suppose we make a change to your code:

```
private static class X implements A {}

B b = new B();
C<? extends A> c = new C<X>(new X());
c.func(b);
```

Now it's more obvious that it shouldn't compile - if you've got a `C<X>`, you don't expect to be able to call `func(b)` where `b` is a `B`, do you? So given that I've *only* changed the right-hand side of the assignment (not the declared type of `c`) it would be very odd for your example to compile but mine not to. Does that help?

As ever, see the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information, particularly the part about [wildcards](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic4).

Answer (score 3):

That line must fail, otherwise this obviously-wrong code *can* compile:

```
private static interface A {}
private static class B implements A {}
private static class B2 implements A {}

@Test
public void doTest() {
    B b = new B();
    B2 b2 = new B2();
    C<? extends A> c = new C<B2>(b2); // B2 extends A, ok.
    c.func(b); // B extends A, but B is not B2, and it should fail.
}
```

Comment: Hah - we were coming up with basically the same example at the same time :)